# Настройки hibernate в файла контекста Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Как определить настройки Hibernate в файлах контекста Spring?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прекрасная [страница по этому поводу](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
На ней видим:

```
# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true # Enable JPA repositories.
spring.jpa.database= # Target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "databasePlatform" property.
spring.jpa.database-platform= # Name of the target database to operate on, auto-detected by default. Can be alternatively set using the "Database" enum.
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false # Initialize the schema on startup.
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= # DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. Default to "create-drop" when using an embedded database, "none" otherwise.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy= # Hibernate 5 implicit naming strategy fully qualified name.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy= # Hibernate 5 physical naming strategy fully qualified name.
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy= # Hibernate 4 naming strategy fully qualified name. Not supported with Hibernate 5.
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings= # Use Hibernate's newer IdentifierGenerator for AUTO, TABLE and SEQUENCE.
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true # Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request.
spring.jpa.properties.*= # Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.
spring.jpa.show-sql=false # Enable logging of SQL statements.
```